# What is the best course of action for fetching a lot of hierarchical records from a table?

Tags: sql, django, database, recursion, recursive-query

I have to render a tree data structure on a user's browser, each node knows its' children (or better, each node knows its' parent). What is the best way to handle a request where the user requests a tree of nodes?

Should I send the whole table, knowing that the user might not require all nodes, but in average 80%?

What is the best strategy for handling such requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the choice between:

- Multiple queries to get 80% of the rows.
- A single query to get 100% of the rows with additional processing on the client side.

Without additional information, either approach seems reasonable.  Assuming that the additional processing is relatively minimal, then the second might be the better solution.  The overhead of running multiple queries may be greater than the overhead of returning an additional 25% of the rows.

However, if this is an important performance consideration, you should test on your system and on your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you hand all the filtering on Server side you are using resources. If you have a lot of users this will slow down your website for all of your users. Especially if you are doing a lot of queries and stuff in the background.

While if you do it on the client side the resources that are spent are on the clients computer. The website/functions would take a little more to load as it has to filter what the user needs.

There are pros and cons. But always make sure that the data that you are sending out is non-confidential data.